# Memory address of a lambda function

Tags: python, lambda, closures

I noticed this behavior in Python 2 and 3:

```
>>> id(lambda: 1) == id(lambda: 2)
True
```

They share the same hash as well.

```
>>> hash(lambda: 1) == hash(lambda: 2)
True
```

I expected to have two **different** `id`s and `hash`es for the two lambda functions.

I investigated more, and I found a similar behavior when returning closures:

```
>>> def foo(n):
...     def bar():
...         return n
...     return bar
... 
>>> id(foo(1)) == id(foo(2))
True
```

In this case, I suppose the `id` is the same because the function returned is exactly the same, and what is changing is **just the enclosing scope**.

Is anything similar happening with `lambda` functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with scope, or lambdas, or closures. It is simply that Python manages memory with reference counting, and those lambdas are never assigned to any references, so Python immediately deletes them and reuses the memory location for the next object.

Comment: Silly me, `a = lambda: 1; b = lambda: 2; id(a) == id(b)` returns `False`. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Daniel, Is it always true that if I create two lambda functions without any name referencing to it will have the same memory locations? I mean it can be sometimes on different memory locations correct?